# How to use nutch-2.2.1 for crawling

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I'm new to Nutch please guys help me to figure out crawling using nutch.Help me to figure out any useful link or document which help me to use nutch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide for setting up with Nutch 1.4. Obviosuly Nutch 2.x has newer features but the older version still provides most, if not all the features you are looking for.

http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html

Comment: thanks for your help I've installed it previously i just wanted to know how to crawl stuffs using nutch in linux environment. As I've configured it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS platform